# Power series formed by terms of a null sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

While showing the existence of radius of convergence, standard proofs make use of the following theorem

**Theorem:** Suppose we have a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ny^n$ which is convergent. Then any series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is absolutely convergent as long as $0<|x|<|y|$.

**Proof:** As $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ny^n$ is convergent, $a_n|y|^n < 1$ for sufficiently large $n$ and for those values of $n$, $a_n|x|^n = a_n|y|^n \times |x/y|^n < |x/y|^n$. As $a_n|x|^n$ is sandwiched between $0$ and $|x/y|^n$ with $|0<|x/y|<1|$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n|x|^n$ is convergent.

Even though the hypothesis is that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ny^n$ is convergent, the proof just makes use of a weaker fact (and I suppose the theorem could have used a weaker hypothesis) that the sequence $(a_ny^n)$ is a null sequence, as in it tends to $0$. This made me wonder about the following problem.

**My Question:** If a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ny^n$ is such that the sequence is a $(a_ny^n)$ is a null sequence, then what can we say about the convergence of the power series?

I know that in general, a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ formed from a null sequence $(a_n)$ need not converge, as is the case with $a_n=1/n$. However, this time, it is a null sequence of the form $(a_ny^n)$. Does that make any difference at all when we have to say something about the convergence of its corresponding power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ny^n$?

Comment: No difference, every null sequence can be written in the form $(a_ny^n)$, just take $y = 1$. And for the Theorem the hypothesis can be weakened to "$(a_ny^n)$ is bounded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every null sequence $(a_n)$ can be written as the terms of a power series — we can trivially take $y = 1$, and if we want it a little less trivial set $b_n = a_ny^{-n}$ for some $y \neq 0$ to have $a_n = b_ny^n$ — it makes no difference, from $a_ny^n \to 0$ we cannot deduce that the power series converges at $y$.

You are right, the theorem can use a weaker hypothesis than convergence, even weaker than your $a_ny^n \to 0$, it suffices that $(a_ny^n)$ is bounded. If $\lvert a_n y^n\rvert \leqslant M$ for all $n$, then we can majorise
$$\lvert a_n x^n\rvert \leqslant M\cdot \biggl\lvert \frac{x}{y}\biggr\rvert^n\,.$$
For every $x$ with $\lvert x\rvert < \lvert y\rvert$ the terms on the right are the terms of a convergent geometric series, whence $\sum a_nx^n$ converges absolutely for $\lvert x\rvert < \lvert y\rvert$.

We thus can characterise the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series as
$$R = \sup\: \{ r \geqslant 0 : a_nr^n \to 0\} = \sup\: \{ r \geqslant 0 : \lvert a_n\rvert r^n \text{ is bounded}\}\,.$$
These are often easier to find than $\limsup \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}$ as used in the Cauchy–Hadamard formula.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Now the reason why I got mixed up about convergence of a power series and the sequence being null is the following. The standard definition of radius of convergence is $ R = \limsup\: \{ r \geqslant 0 : \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n \text{ is convergent} \}$ while we could have defined it the way you have defined, namely $\sup\: \{ r \geqslant 0 : \lvert a_n\rvert r^n \text{ is bounded}\}$ or as $\sup\: \{ r \geqslant 0 : \text{ the sequence } (a_n r^n) \text{ is a null sequence}\}$. I presume radius of convergence is unique so both definitions should give the same value.

Comment: However, one uses convergence of a series, and the other uses just the boundedness or the sequence being null. Though the sequence being null does not imply that the series is convergent, we still get the same value for the radius of convergence no matter which of the two options you use. In other words, the radius is a limit of both the qualities, namely convergence of the series, and the sequence being null even though null sequences need not end up in a power series which is convergent! Don't you find that interesting?

Comment: Yes, it is interesting. The reason is of course that the behaviour of $n \mapsto r^n$ changes drastically when you choose $r$ even a tiny bit larger or smaller. Contrast that with Dirichlet series ($\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n n^{-s}$). The change of growth of $n \mapsto n^{-\sigma}$ when you change $\sigma$ is much slower. So much slower that $a_n n^{-\sigma_0} \to 0$ doesn't imply convergence for all $\sigma > \sigma_0$, and you can even have a strip (of width $\leqslant 1$) where the series converges only conditionally between the half-planes of divergence and of absolute convergence.

Comment: For power series you immediately go from absolute convergence to unboundedness of the terms (where "immediately" means the two domains have a common boundary; on the boundary of the disk of convergence various interesting things can happen).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So the fact that you go immediately from absolute convergence to unboundedness means the following proposition. 

 **Proposition:** The power sequence sequence $(a_nr^n)$ is a null sequence (i.e its limit is $0$) if and only if the power series
 $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n$ is convergent, with a possible exception of
 $|r|=|R|$.

 This is exactly same as what I had originally suspected which is that if a power *sequence* is null, then the power *series* converges (opposite direction is well established). Where am I going wrong in my thought process?

Comment: You already mentioned the possible exception when $\lvert r\rvert = R$. On the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$, various things can happen. The sequence $(a_nR^n)$ can be unbounded; it can be bounded but not a null sequence (in these two cases it is clear that the series diverges on the whole boundary circle); finally, it can be a null sequence. This last case has interesting subcases, 1. the power series can diverge on the whole circle, 2. the power series converges [conditionally] at some points of the boundary circle and diverges at others

Comment: (this leads to the interesting classification problem which sets on the circle can be the sets of convergence), 3. the power series converges conditionally on the whole circle (which interestingly does not imply that the sum function is continuous on the closed disk), 4. the power series converges absolutely on the whole circle (in which case the convergence is absolute and uniform on the closed disk, so the sum function is continuous there). What we can generally say is that when $(a_nr^n)$ is a null sequence, then the power series converges absolutely on the disk $\lvert z\rvert < r$,

Comment: and we can already say that when the sequence is bounded [and we can even go beyond that, it suffices that the sequence grows slower than exponentially].